# Best method to incorporate a variable in command syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium

I am looking for the optimal way to create a function that allows me to provide args into an Appium locator command. But in order to do that, I need a way to input variables in the command. Here is an example of a basic command:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@text='Get Started' or @id='get_started']")))
```

What I am looking to do in my function is to make the following configurable:

1. The @ method, which can be various things, e.g text or id.
2. The specific value of the @ method, e.g 'get_started'

I have tried just assigning it to a variable but this is just throwing meaningless errors saying the element cannot be located. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you wanted to do this _right_, that would call for using (or building) a proper parser/generator for XPath. If no such library exists, you might want to look into what alternatives are available to `By.XPATH`. How feasible doing it _wrong_ is depends on the details -- whether you need every possible string to be able to be injected or are dealing with only a constricted input domain -- and generally those details (for an approach that would work with all possible data) are too broad to fit into a Stack Overflow question's scope (hence why using a library is the Right Thing).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
                some_variable = 'text'
                some_text = 'Get Started'                    
                WebDriverWait(self.driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@"+some_variable+"=\""+some_text+"\"]")))
```